# Check if string already exist in Table

Tags: c#, linq

I want to check if the email that user entered already exist in Office table,take a look bellow what I have done so far, the problem is that `officeEmail` is always true, even though the entered email doesn't exist it's never returning `NULL`.

```
public static bool IsOfficeEmail(string email)
{

    using (var data = Database)
    {
        data.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
        var officeEmail = data.Offices.Where(a => a.Active && a.Email.Equals(email));

        if (officeEmail != null)                
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) will not return you null, but empty sequence, change it to:

```
var officeEmail = data.Offices.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Active && a.Email.Equals(email));

if (officeEmail != null)                
    return true;
```

[`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) will return default value (here null) it will not find queried value.

It is an option to use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any(v=vs.100).aspx) if you are not interested in email record:

```
public static bool IsOfficeEmail(string email)
{
    using (var data = Database)
    {
        return data.Offices.Any(a => a.Active && a.Email.Equals(email))
    }
}
```

You will not get email record if you will not use it anyway. Which approach you should use depends on what will you do with `officeEmail`, if you are just querying if it exists -> `Any` will be the best approach here. If you would like to get check for existing record and do something with it, `FirstOrDefault` will be better.

Comment: for explenation of when to favour `Any` over `FirstOrDefault`. +1

Comment: Thank you for the answer and also very good explanation, therefore I could learn something.

Answer (score 2):

Alternativly if you really want to use `.Where` you can also check if the returned collection contains ANY elements:

```
if (officeMail.Any()) // ...
```

Or even shorter:

```
if (officeMail.Any(a => a.Active && a.Email.Equals(email))) // ...
```

If you want to ensure that there is exactly ONE item within your list matching your condition use `.Single` instead of `.Any` which will throw an exception if none or more then one item was found.

The actual reason for your check allways returning `true` is that `.Where` will return an enumerator even when no item matches the condition. Therefor the result is never `null`.